# Image is not appearing responsive

Tags: css, reactjs

In react app images is not appearing responsive. In app container 2 divs right and left. Right is text, left is Image. Even `display:block` in the media quire is not working.

Please help.
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-waterfall-y6br1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: check your link. it just shows "hello codesandbox"

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-waterfall-y6br1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

It's about your css.
Change your image class's css.

```
.image {
  /* max-width: 400px; */ /* OPTIONAL => if you want to limit your width*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```